# Vuetify v-text field minimum height limitation?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i have a v-text-field and i'm trying to set the height to 37px but it seems like the minimum height has to be 49px. Is there a way to override this? I tried putting custom css but it seems like it works in the chrome inspector but i am not able to target it somehow

I have made a codepen with custom css styling applied but cannot seem to make it work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMEmex

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
   <v-container>
   <v-text-field solo placeholder="trying to adjust the height" 
   height="37px"></v-text-field>
   </v-container>
  </v-app>
  </div>

   new Vue({
 el: '#app'
    })
```

When i apply this css on .v-input-slot in the chrome inspector tools, it seem to work

```
  .v-input__slot {
  min-height: auto !important;
 display: flex !important;
 align-items: center !important;
 }
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your css selector should be:

```
 .v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
    min-height: auto !important;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
  }
```

Demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/gNGRbB)

Comment: Boom. I knew i was doing something(or most things) wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

use dense

```
<v-text-field dense></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on [ittus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303610/ittus) answer but it will also shrink the text-field **label**, **icons** and **details** accordingly.

```
.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot {
  min-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 8px !important;
  margin-bottom: 2px !important;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}

.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot .v-input__append-inner {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot label {
  margin-top: -12px !important;
}

.v-text-field .v-input__control .v-input__slot label.v-label--active {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px !important;
}

.v-text-field__details {
  margin: 2px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. remove `scoped` attribute from `<style>` section
2. set custom class on element, for example `class="custom-class"`
3. set custom css style on any nested element , for example `.custom-class .any-nested-element-class {min-height: 32px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Sub case v-app-bar in Vue 3:

I was trying to put a `v-text-input` in a `v-app-bar` for global search. Even with `density=compact` component is still 64px and does fit proper. The issue is this (quite complex) component has a normally hidden (but still rendered) details area underneath the input (presumably for validation feedback). If you disable that with `hide-details` prop and set `density=compact` it's 42px which fit nicely in v-app-bar and aligns vertically properly.

Answer (score 0):

After I try to customize `min-height`  but nothing happen

It work fine after custom size of sass variable

```
$text-field-filled-full-width-outlined-dense-slot-min-height: 34px !default;
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#sass